# TemplateDoesNotExist at /home/ internal server error Django

Tags: django, django-templates

my html file isn't displaying.
folder path:
D:\New folder\core\core\home
[View.py file in home app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTIvq.png)
D:\New folder\core\core\home
[urls.py file in home app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMbWP.png)
D:\New folder\core\core
[urls.py file in core project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVqxX.png)
D:\New folder\core\core
[Settings.py file in core project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtmpk.png)
[index.html file in template which is in template file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Byn28.png)

```
Tried every step help me solving this
```

when i change folder name from template to templates
[template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQcwR.png)
[templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3NSX.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename the folder `template` to `templates`.

Comment: if i changed the file name from template to templates I'm unable to create html file

Comment: Not file name, but folder name (maybe there was a typo in your comment). Also, if you meant folder name, you could post a screenshot of how you're attempting to create an html file inside the folder and you're unable to do that.

Comment: will add the screenshot

Comment: i have added the screen shots

Comment: Your screenshot looks well, now the folder name is correct now. You should be able to create files in it, if I correctly understood the issue you encountered in your first comment.

Comment: its working ! thank you < i think i need to change the folder name before running the command python manage.py runserver, and to edit the html file by changing the folder name to template

Comment: Yes, you need to first rename the folder and then run the server. Also, if you found my answer helpful, please mark it as accepted.